# "Recyceln" oder "recycelt" mit den Kollektiva "Menschen" und "Leute"?

Tags: grammar, conjugation

> Einerseits gibt es in Südamerika viele Menschen, die "recyceln" und ihren Müll weniger macht. Andererseits gibt es Leute, die einfach nicht "recycelt".

Sind meine Sätze korrekt?

Comment: "Leute" benötigt Plural, also "recyclen". – Warum switchst du im ersten Satz zu einer Singular Konjugation "macht" im zweiten Teil des Satzes?

Comment: weil ich so verwirrt bin :) Ein muss korrekt sein!

Comment: Ist es vielleicht "machen"?

Comment: Ja, "machen" ist richtig. Und "recyceln" (oder "recyclen" mit E und L vertauscht) in beiden Sätzen. – Die Sätze klingen dennoch nicht sehr schön. Ein Muttersprachler würde es mit Sicherheit anders formulieren.

Comment: Danke schoen!!! Du bist der Beste :D

Comment: @breakstorm: Beachte, dass wir kein Korrekturdienst sind. Beschreibe bitte, wo Du Dir unsicher bist und wieso. So ist die Frage auch für andere nützlich. Siehe auch [How to deal with 'Is it correct' questions?](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/669/2594).

Comment: Satz1: und somit ihren Müll verringern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Einerseits gibt es in Südamerika viele Menschen, die "recyceln" und ihren Müll weniger macht. Andererseits gibt es Leute, die einfach nicht "recycelt".

It's nearly correct. I, as a German, would link the phrases so there would only be one, but your sentences are perfectly fine. The quotation marks aren't neccessary and would probably confuse a bit. *Recyclen* can be written as *recyclen* and *recyceln*, it depends on your choise ([Link to duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/recyceln)). *Macht* should be replaced by *machen* for a correct conjugation. Same goes for your last sentence, where *recycelt* should be replaced with *recyceln*.
*Weniger machen* could be replaced by *reduzieren*, which means *reducing* in English, but that's up to you.
This would be my revised sentence:

> Einerseits gibt es in Südamerika viele Menschen, die recyceln und weniger Müll machen. Andererseits gibt es Leute, die einfach nicht recyceln.

Comment: "Ihren Müll weniger machen" klingt falsch. Wie wäre es mit "die weniger Müll machen"?

Comment: Hm, stimmt, da habe ich auch etwas gestockt, bin aber auf keine passende Umschreibung gekommen. Werde ich verbessern

Comment: ... und statt *einerseits/andererseits* würde mir persönlich *zwar/aber* besser gefallen, aber das ist Geschmackssache :)

Comment: @Takkat Da ich nicht wusste, ob er evtl die beiden Sätze aus Übungen hatte, habe ich das lieber so gelassen, da Einerseits und Andererseits relativ auffällig waren und vielleicht trainiert werden sollten.

Comment: Ja klar, das kann man ja auch so lassen. Eine "einzig richtige" Formulierung gibt's sowieso nicht.

Comment: Man kann Müll nicht vermeiden, aber man kann vermeiden, zu viel Müll zu machen. Die vorherige Version (weniger Müll machen) war deutlich besser. Oder man fügt noch ein Wort an wie "übermäßig" -> "... die recyclen und dadurch übermäßigen Müll vermeiden"

Answer (score 0):

Einerseits gibt es in Südamerika viele Menschen, die recyceln und dadurch weniger Müll produzieren . Andererseits gibt es Leute, die einfach nicht recyceln.